# How to repeat the same Qiskit instruction $N$ times (no for loop)?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

I need to build the following 1-qubit `QuantumCircuit` in Qiskit, repeating the pair ($X$ gate, barrier) for $N$ times:

[image]

The most straightforward way to do this is by using a `for` loop in Python:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

N = 10000
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
for i in range(N):
    qc.x(0)
    qc.barrier()
```

But this could become very slow if you try to build hundreds/thousands of very deep circuits. So here's my question: is there a way to do it without looping?

Comment: How deep is "very deep"? How's your use case?

Comment: "very deep" means up to several tens of thousands of layers. I'm running mock circuits to experimentally measure the impact of different kinds of noise.

Comment: Each circuit is unique, or there is similarity between these circuits?

Comment: I basically always have the same type of circuit, consisting in a variable number $N$ of repetitions for the same sequence of gates..

Comment: Do you mean to avoid 'for' loops and use vectorization?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean by vectorization in this case. I simply mean avoid bare Python loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you have asked for, it is possible to use either the [`repeat`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.repeat.html) or [`power`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.power.html) methods of a `QuantumCircuit` instance:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

N = 10000
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)

qc.x(0)
qc.barrier()

qc = qc.repeat(N)
```

If you try now to draw you circuit the output would be $N$ circuits-blocks in a row. You can overcome that using `qc.decompose(reps=2).draw()`.

Comment: I wonder whether you really have the same circuit repeated N times after the compilation?

Comment: Thank you! This looks like the most simple yet efficient solution.

Comment: @M.stern indeed. What makes you wonder it doesn't?

Comment: Because there is a lot of optimization and routing happening under the hood, which uses heuristics that may not yield deterministic outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

If each circuit is same as the previous one with additional gates, then instead of starting over each time you can use the already created circuit and append the extra gates to it.

The following code snippet demonstrates the idea:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from time import time

start_time = time()

circ = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)

for N in range(1, 1001):
    # Remove "measure" instruction if exists
    if len(circ.data) > 1:
        del circ.data[len(circ.data) - 1]

    for i in range(100):
        circ.x(0)
        circ.barrier()
    circ.measure(0, 0)
    #run(backend, circ)
    if N % 100 == 0:
        print('# Circuits: {0}, Largest Depth: {1}, Time: {2} s'.format(N, circ.depth(), round(time() - start_time), 2))
```

The output:

```
# Circuits: 100, Largest Depth: 10001, Time: 1 s
# Circuits: 200, Largest Depth: 20001, Time: 1 s
# Circuits: 300, Largest Depth: 30001, Time: 2 s
# Circuits: 400, Largest Depth: 40001, Time: 3 s
# Circuits: 500, Largest Depth: 50001, Time: 4 s
... ... ...
```

And the result of simulating the first few circuits:

[image]

Note: I'm assuming here that your circuits are not dynamic. That is, circuit instructions don't use the measurement results.

Comment: This solution clearly uses a 'for' loop

Comment: What I understand from the question is that he doesn't want to use `for` loop to avoid the bad performance. It looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. And I could be wrong.